# Debugging Event code

Tags: android, debugging, event-handling

If I wish to debug some code for a UI event, e.g.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
{
    // code to be debugged
}
```

... and I hold onto this thread (UI):

After 5 seconds I will get this warning: Key dispatching timed out sending to com.hos/com.hos.MyActivity ... null to Window ...

After 20 seconds I will get: Key dispatching timed out sending to com.hos/com.hos.MyActivity ... null to Window ... Continuing to wait for key to be dispatched

After 35 seconds I will get: Key dispatching timed out sending to com.hos/com.hos.MyActivity ... null to Window ... timed out expired process next Key & find new target

At this point, not only is my application frozen but so is the phone. Quite often I need to wait for the ANR and sometimes hard restart the phone.

Is there a way to debug this code for more than 35 seconds without freezing the app / phone?

Comment: You could write a (JUnit) test class which calls this method with constructed input -- so that the testing is decoupled from having to be run with the GUI?

Comment: @paiego: where you able in the end to solve this issue? I still run into this problem when, for some reason, I _need_ to debug an instrumented test case on the simulator.

Comment: @superjos, Sorry but I haven't yet found a better solution than to use logging rather than step-tracing.

Answer (score 0):

If your processing may take more than milliseconds to process you may want to consider launching the processing in another thread which has access to a handler in the main thread.

Once you are done processing, you can then pass a message over to your handler which will then execute on the UI thread.  This will help prevent those errors from coming up as well as make debugging your code easier.

If you are looking for an automated UI testing framework, perhaps you could look into integrating Robotium into your project.

Comment: and @arve... sincere thanks, but I'm not having any problems w/ debugging or testing of the code; i'm just concerned that the system gets hosed whenever I hold onto the thread.